# Can't make my search bar float to the left

Tags: css, search

I hope you all are doing great.

I just wanted to see how my website would look if I moved logo to the right, and the search bar to the left. I edited the style.css to make the logo float right, but when doing that with the search bar, nothing moves ,I tried "center"-ing it and putting it to the "left" but it won't work. Here have a look at some of the code :

```
/* Horizontal Category List (Default & Flyout) */

#SideCategoryList h2 {
display: block;
border-bottom: #ACA9A9 dashed 1px;
}

/* Logo */
#Logo {
float: left;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#Logo h1 {
font-size: 63px;
font-weight: normal !important;
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-transform: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 15px;
font-family: 'Sacramento', Arial, Sans-Serif;
letter-spacing: normal;
}
#Logo #LogoImage {
}


/* Top Search Form */
#SearchForm{
margin: 15px 0 0 0;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
position: relative;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #ACA9A9;
overflow: auto;
float: center;
}
#SearchForm form {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
#SearchForm label {
display: none;
}
#SearchForm input {
color: #aca9a9;
width: 145px;
height: 18px;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 2px 3px 2px 3px;
```

Comment: Hi Altin - welcome to StackOverflow. A jsFiddle of the html and the CSS would be a great help. jsfiddle.net

Comment: Float:center is invalid .... and exactly what happen when you set folat:left?? ... who are the main container ?? how looks you markup?

Comment: I'm using a built-in theme from mybigcommerce(.)com and don't have any idea which is the main container. When I set the SearchForm float to the left, it won't move, it just sits right were it was. Here take a look on the actual website : http://love-a-gram.mybigcommerce.com/